# Как в Angular собрать сервис, компонент отдельным чанком?

Tags: angular, webpack

```
Есть сервис A
Есть компонент A
Есть компонент B
```

Оба компонента используют сервис A -
исходя из стандартной логики - чанка будет два.
Это значит что сервис A будет дублироваться и оба чанка станут больше на размер сервиса A.

Я видел - толи это вебпак толи в ангуляре прописывали - что б типа сказать - сбилди это отдельным чанком! Но нигде сейчас не найду решения.
Что б загрузился чанк с сервисом A, потом компонент один, и потом второй, но они без сервиса были....

Но как я понял - сейчас с новым ангуляром 17 динамически если подгружать компоненты, то они автоматом упакуются в отдельные чанки....но здесь больше вообще о подходе разделения чанков.
Я не беру во внимание lazy load components/modules так как этот компонент может включать сервис, который ещё будет в десятке других компонентов и мне не хотелось бы что б все компоненты разбухали от дублирования данных.

Спасибо

Comment: Убедитесь, что ваш сервис A объявлен как singleton во всем приложении. Это гарантирует, что будет создан только один экземпляр сервиса, независимо от того, в каких чанках он используется. Обычно это достигается путем предоставления сервиса в корневом модуле (AppModule)